# Android Accessibility for the Google legacy sign-in flow

Tags: android, accessibility, google-signin

We're using original Google sign-in in our app (as opposed to newer improved option One-tap) https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

So user clicks the **Login with Google** button, user's presented a similar DialogFragment to this one to choose an account to sign in with:

[image]

Now imagine you change your mind and want to login using other way. Tapping outside of the dialog fragment dismisses it.

But for a user of TalkBack that is visually impaired, we noticed that once you're presented with that dialog, there's no way to close it since no close button is displayed and no other interaction to dismiss is possible. So as a user of TalkBack you're trapped and have to close the app and reopen to be able to dismiss that dialog.

Users of talkback might know or not that "Down then left" gesture (https://pauljadam.com/demos/talkbackcheatsheet.html) is the same as phone's physical back button/swipe to go back, but they need to be aware they're on a floating dialog and I don't think this was clear either.

Is there any way to add an explicit close button to the native dialog?

One tap's bottom sheet has a dismiss button, tho one is not a replacement for the other.

Thank you;

Comment: Have you tried raising the issue with https://issuetracker.google.com?

Comment: Good point. Created: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/190075878
Cheers!

Comment: I've subscribed to the updates, I don't know how else to show I care... I have a few issues there myself and I don't hear anything back from them. I think in the meantime you'll probably have to add something in, unfortunately